# Sitecore SXA Clone without subitems is cloning all the subitems for the bucketable item

Tags: sxa, buckets

I am using Sitecore 10.1 with SXA. I have two sites under DC Decorio tenant.

[image]

I want to move a bucketable item from one site to another. The item looks like this.

[image]

When I use the option called Clone without Subitems under Configure tab, it clones the item including all the subitems. That is not the expected behaviour. Does anyone face a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is happening only if you clone a Bucket item, for all other items it works as expected and only the selected item will be cloned. In the case of buckets this is implemented by the processors defined in the pipeline `<buckets.cloneItemIntoBucket>` from the config file `/App_Config/Sitecore/Buckets/Sitecore.Buckets.config`:

```
<buckets.cloneItemIntoBucket>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.ItemOperations.CloneItem.RunCloning, Sitecore.Buckets"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.ItemOperations.CloneItem.ProcessParentReference, Sitecore.Buckets"/>
</buckets.cloneItemIntoBucket>
```

I wouldn't recommend changing the default sitecore behavior unless it is really necessary as sitecore is running various functionalities on the bucketable items. To bypass the current implementation you would need to override the `RunCloning` processor so that it doesn't clone the subitems or try to also look and override the `<uiCloneItems>` processor implementation so that it calls the clone only for the current item.

Comment: So is there any way to run it like the expected behavior?

Comment: Updated the answer.